# How to implement multi language models using loopback

Tags: json, node.js, strongloop, loopback

Id like to build an API with strongloop loopback that includes models with multiple language strings.
E.g. products that have their titles in multiple languages.

Id like to store the objects like

```
{
  "price": 10
  "title": {
    "en": "englishTitle",
    "de": "germanTitle"
  }
}
```

Whats the best way to define a model like this in loopback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use related model for multi language titles. So you master model, say, `Product` has related model `Title` using `hasMany` relation. You'll be able query required language title for your particular product. Here is one of possible examples.

Model `Product`

```
{
  "name": "Product",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "price": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "defaultTitle": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "titles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Title",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Model `Title`

```
{
  "name": "Title",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "language": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "product": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Product",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Then you may query `Product` including related `Title` and using filtering with required language. `defaultTitle` is optional of course.

Comment: In my Case I added a localisedString model, so I could generalize this across multiple attributes like this, what do you think of this approach?:

{
  "name": "LocalizedString",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": false,
    "en": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "cn": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}

Comment: I think that approach is good but your implementation is not so good. How will your model be related with your parent model? Are you going to change model (and database) structure if you need another language? Simply try to use your proposed solution to make sure if it's good. Also you can search here at Stackoverflow for *localization database structure* or something of that kind for more general answers. It's good to make some learning on design of database structure theory. I'm talking about using relational database.